# Sketching a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Sketch the dynamical system

\begin{align}
\dot x_1 = x_2 \\
\dot x_2 = 1
\end{align}

Firstly we may integrate this to find

$$x_2(t) = t + A$$
$$x_1(t) = \frac12t^2+At + B$$

How do I then change this into an equation that I can plot in the $(x_1,x_2)$ plane?

Comment: You can plot the vector field and the integral curves before/without finding the solutions

Comment: I am a little late here but if you are to sketch the dynamical system you should probably heed the comment by @MarcoDisce. If this is an assignment, your teacher may be asking for the vector field and not a particular solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ t=x_2-A$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1=\frac{(x_2-A)^2}{2}+A(x_2-A)+B$$
$$\Rightarrow 2x_1=x_2^2 +A^2-2Ax_2+2Ax_2 -2A^2 +2B$$
$$\Rightarrow 2x_1=x_2^2-A^2+2B$$

It is a parabola in $(x_1, x_2)$ plane

Answer (score 1):

$x_1= 1/2(t+A)^2+C= {x_2^2\over 2}+C$, or $x_1-{x_2^2\over 2}=C$, a one parameter family of parallel parabols with horizontal axis.